# Jackson - Custom deserialization only to some map entries

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

Suppose a JSON representation of `Map<String, Object>`. I want to deserialize it as default except by two entries (`List<Foo>` and `Bar`), which I want a custom deserialization.

Is it possible?

First approach. I tried with a `BeanDeserializerModifier`. The problem is that it allows assign a custom deserialization by type, not by name of the entry.

In other words I have been able to change how a map is deserialized, but I want all other entries will be deserialized as default.

```
class MapTypeJsonDeserializer extends SimpleDeserializers {

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> findMapDeserializer (MapType type, DeserializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, KeyDeserializer keyDeserializer, TypeDeserializer elementTypeDeserializer, JsonDeserializer<?> elementDeserializer) throws JsonMappingException {
        return new CustomMapDeserializer();
    }
}

class CustomMapDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Map<String, Object>> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> deserialize (JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JacksonException {
        // trying to remove entries which I want a custom deserialization
        JsonNode node = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
        ((ObjectNode) node).remove("foo");
        ((ObjectNode) node).remove("bar");

        // trying to deserialize other entries as default... 
        String updatedJson = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(node);
        JsonParser updatedJsonParser = new JsonFactory().createParser(updatedJson);

        // error trying to call super class (is abstract) to deserialize as default
        Map<String, Object> result = super.deserialize(updatedJsonParser, deserializationContext);

        // finally I would try to add custom deserialization entries to resulting map...
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    SimpleModule mapTypeDeserializerModule = new SimpleModule();
    mapTypeDeserializerModule.setDeserializers(new MapTypeJsonDeserializer());
    String jsonMap = "{\"someEntry\":\"ES\",\"foo\":[{...}, {...}],\"bar\":{...}";
    
    Map<String, String> resultMap = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(mapTypeDeserializerModule).readValue(jsonMap, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {});
}
```

How can I deserialize all other map entries as default?

Another idea was to create custom deserializers for `Foo` and `Bar` types, but I want to store them in map as `JsonNode` because this classes are not in my classpath and I can't build and instance of them.

I don't know if is possible create a custom deserializer which for a type `Foo` returns a `JsonNode`, something like that obviously do not compile:

```
class FooDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Foo> {

    @Override
    public Foo deserialize (JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JacksonException {
        JsonNode node = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
        return node;
    }
}
```

In short, I want to deserialize a `Map<String, Object>` as default except by some entries which contains some types that I need to keep, but I cannot build an instance of these because its classes is not in classpath (that's why I tried to keep them as original JSON like `JsonNode`).

Another idea was use a `BeanDeserializerModifier` to assign a custom deserializer to `Foo` and `Bar`, but this lead me to create a deserializer for `Foo`/`Bar` that returns a `JsoNode` (same problem as above).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can add a wrapper layer to achieve your goal, e.g: `List<Foo>` => `List<FooView<Foo>>`, `Bar` => `BarView<Bar>` , then you can control them since it created by yourself.

Comment: @holi-java can you expand the explanation of your solution? How would be `FooView` and `BarView`? How can deserialize map entries `Foo` as `FooView` and `Bar` as `BarView` and all other entries as default?

Comment: `FooWiew` is just a pojo take a `Foo` instance with your custom getters. No need to write your Deserializer.

Comment: You are creating `new ObjectMapper()` and `new JsonFactory()` every time you deserialize. This is very wasteful (lots of repeated work, constantly garbage collecting)

Comment: @holi-java I can't even declare `List<FooView<Foo>>` because Foo class is not in my classpath.

Comment: @lance-java is just an example for the sake of brevity, in the real code I don't create them every time.